# Problems with manage.py in django

Tags: python, database, postgresql, manage.py

I am attempting to run a site from my localhost. What I did is I first cloned the repo and pull it into my local directory. Then, I changed the DB part to my DB settings. I have tried python manage.py runserver, python manage.py migrate and python manage.py makemigrations, but it still shows the same error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgSBF.png)

I have tried different solutions found online, but they don't seem to work. I think the main problem is that I'm not sure where the problem is. I have tried creating a superuser, but it still shows the same error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but may I know what you need?